# Two MySQL relations in one entry?

Tags: mysql, relational-database

My question is: Is it possible to create two MySQL relations in one dataentry?

**Sample:**

*Structure:*

```
Table: QUEST
```

Colums: questId, questRewardTypeId

```
Table: REWARD_TYPE
```

Colums:
rewardId, rewardDesc

*Data:*

*One data line is `{}`*

QUEST:

```
{1, LEVEL AND MONEY}
```

REWARD_TYPE:

```
{LEVEL, Level reward}, {MONEY, money reward}, {ITEM, item reward}
```

[image: Database relations]

Comment: You might be able to do this using JSON or possibly CSV, but this would likely not be relational, and possibly bad table/database design.

Comment: thank you for your fast answer. JSON is a solution but not the finest. is it possible to safe it with mysql relations?

Comment: Can you show us data in tabular form?

Comment: To me you have a many to many between quest and reward types.  A reward type could be used by many quests and a quest can have zero to many reward types.  So you need an associative table `QuestRewards` which resolves the many-to-many.  This way a quest could have zero to many rewards associated. and a reward could be associated to zero to many quests.  In addition you could have additional fields on the QuestRewards table to specify different items or values.

Comment: Yes, i send you a link: http://imgur.com/WTSPWcb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the two tables `QUEST` and `REWARD_TYPE`, each with their primary key (`questId` and `rewardTypeId`), the usual way is to create a third table that links data sets from both tables by their primary keys. This allows to have more than one reward entry for a quest.

Let's call the table `QUEST_REWARD` and give it the following structure:

```
+--------------+--------------+
| Field        | Type         |
+--------------+--------------+
| questId      | int(10)      |
| rewardTypeId | varchar(255) |
+--------------+--------------+
```

The types should match those of the keys in `QUEST` and `REWARD_TYPE`.

Then you can create an entry for each reward type that a quest provides. For example, if a quest provides a new level and money, the SQL statements could be:

```
INSERT INTO QUEST_REWARD SET questId=1, rewardTypeId='LEVEL';
INSERT INTO QUEST_REWARD SET questId=1, rewardTypeId='MONEY';
```

Now you can get all the rewards for a quest by using the following query (here for the quest with id 1):

```
SELECT * from QUEST_REWARD WHERE questId = 1;
```

... and the result would be:

```
+---------+--------------+
| questId | rewardTypeId |
+---------+--------------+
|       1 | LEVEL        |
|       1 | MONEY        |
+---------+--------------+
```

Of course, **you can extend that for any number of reward types**, not just two per quest. Moreover, it is also easier to query for than any JSON or CSV approaches that were brought up in the comments, because you can save yourself the hassle of parsing that stuff into its components.